# Why is Solve unable to solve the given equation?

Tags: equation-solving

Here is my Mathematica code:

```
$Assumptions = {r ∈ Reals, r >= 0, rh ∈ Reals, 
   rh > 0, Q ∈ Reals, Q >= 0, α ∈ Reals, α > 0, 
   P ∈ Reals, P >= 0, L ∈ Reals, L > 0};
M[α_, rh_, Q_, P_] := (3 π rh^2)/8 (1 + (2 α)/rh^2 + (4 π P rh^2)/3) + (π Q^2)/(8 rh^2)

f[α_, r_, rh_, Q_, P_] := 1 + r^2/(4 α) (1 - 
     Sqrt[1 + (64  α  M[α, rh, Q, P])/(3 Pi r^4) - (
       8 α Q^2)/(3 r^6) - (32 Pi α P)/3])

Veff[r_] = f[α, r, rh, Q, P] (L^2/r^2 + 1);

eqn1 = Veff'[r0] == 0 // Simplify;

sol = Block[{α = 0.01, L = 20, Q = 0.2}, Solve[eqn1, r0, Reals]]
```

where I need to find the value of `r0` in terms of `P` and `rh`. I even tried simplifying the expression of `eqn1` below:

```
eqn2 = L^2 == (r0^3*D[f[α, r0, rh, Q, P], r0])/(2  f[α, r0, rh, Q, P] - 
        r0  D[f[α, r0, rh, Q, P], r0]) // Simplify;

sol = Block[{α = 0.01, L = 20, Q = 0.2}, Solve[eqn2, r0, Reals]]
```

But still, it is unable to provide me with any solution unless I provide it with a value for `P`. What should I try?

Comment: You should not really be using machine numbers with exact solvers like `Solve`. Better to use exact numbers.

Comment: @Nasser, I would always rationalize my constants before using Solve from now on. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

$Assumptions = {r ∈ Reals, r >= 0, rh ∈ Reals, 
   rh > 0, Q ∈ Reals, 
   Q >= 0, α ∈ Reals, α > 0, 
   P ∈ Reals, P >= 0, L ∈ Reals, L > 0};

M[α_, rh_, Q_, 
  P_] := (3  π  rh^2)/
    8  (1 + (2  α)/rh^2 + (4  π  P  rh^2)/
      3) + (π  Q^2)/(8  rh^2)

f[α_, r_, rh_, Q_, P_] := 
 1 + r^2/(4  α)  (1 - 
     Sqrt[1 + (64   α   M[α, rh, Q, 
           P])/(3  Pi  r^4) - (8  α  Q^2)/(3  r^6) - (32  Pi  \
α  P)/3])

Veff[r_] = f[α, r, rh, Q, P]  (L^2/r^2 + 1);

sol = Block[{α = 1/100, L = 20, Q = 1/5},
  Solve[Numerator[Veff'[r0] // FullSimplify] == 0, r0, Reals]]
```

[image]